# How to get records from MySQL in c/c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, c

This is pretty easy in PHP:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:".$LOCAL_DB_PORT, $LOCAL_DB_USER, $LOCAL_DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
mysql_query("set names utf8", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select ...");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
...
}
```

But what's the easiest way to do it with c/c++ in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details)
{
     // first of all create a mysql instance and initialize the variables within
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    // connect to the database with the details attached.
    if (!mysql_real_connect(connection,mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      printf("Conection error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
      exit(1);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

For a working example take a look at: http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/02/17/mysql-connection-example/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get hold of MySql Connector/C++.  Information on download and usage is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html).

If licensing constraints prevent this, you can use [Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html).

Comment: Is there a connector in `c` ?

Comment: @ollydbg - yes, check out the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html